# explaining structure of a certain date/time-format

Tags: date

Weird question, I know, but can anybody translate this date/time-format? Or explain how this is structured?

```
1420212174
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you provide some context or a guess at what sort of data is encoded here? Or additional examples?

Comment: it is supposed to be a signup-date. other examples: `1420662937` `1420458113` `1420382092`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the number of seconds elapsed since the Unix Epoch: 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970.

The date is: Friday, 2 January 2015, 15:22:54

Comment: How did you know that??!

Comment: And for further reference the name of this kind of format is "timestamp"

Comment: @Celt :-)  I've just finished working on a system that uses Unix Epoch timestamps for logging, so I'm somewhat familiar with numbers in that range.

Comment: @b.enoit.be Probably Unix Epoch Timestamp?  See this [EpochConverter](http://www.epochconverter.com) tool.

Comment: @MikeofSST not specifically, MySQL uses the same timestamp and most of the OS do, although they do not rely on the same "start date"

Comment: @b.enoit.be Yes, Timestamp is the correct general term.  The question was about a specific variant, so my suggestion names that one.  I've upvoted your comment because it does highlight that other variants, with different start dates, do exist.